# Why does Windows 10 loop infinitely when I have it getting the folder size of multiple-dot-foldernames

Tags: windows, directory

I created a folder "test" plus 2 folders named "....." and "......" inside "test"
When I now try to get the properties of folder test with a right click Windows counts the folder size infinitely.

Can someone explain, why?

Comment: How did you create the folders?

Comment: Inside git bash for Windows

Comment: Well, looks like you found an Explorer bug.  Not completely mystifying, it does have to treat directories named `..` specially.  Consider picking better names.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like windows misinterprets `.` and `..` in windows represent current dir and father dir, in your case the shell gets confused and start a never-ending recursion.

For this situation windows explorer rises errors, but not git, so you have to rremember to avoid this sort of names while using git-bash.

It's definetly a git-bash unhandled situation that causes errors on windows